# Transfer of mutual funds

Tags: mutual-funds, foreign-exchange, european-union, sweden

Say that I have some mutual funds invested in a (Swedish) bank, in Swedish crowns. If I move to another (EU) country, will I be able to transfer the funds without cashing them? This would imply changing to a country with different currency (Euros).

Note: also, it seems that cashing mutual funds has a 30% flat rate tax on the benefits here in Sweden. The country I'd move to will have a lower tax (20% for those quantities, as is not a flat rate).

Answer (score 1):

Moving your residence is unrelated to if you can keep them.  If you want to move your investments to another brokerage/bank, it depends on them if they support accounts in the old currency, and/or if the investments are tradable on other exchanges / in other currencies.

Regarding your tax question- most countries tax income in the year it happens, so if you live in a different country when you sell the investments, that's whee you pay the taxes, according to *their* tax laws. However, if you leave it in the bank in the old country, they might tax you too.

Comment: If I own a fund in Europe, my statement shows Euros. The identical fund would be valued as Dollars if I am in the US or Canada. Why would a sale be required, isn't it the same fund? Just as a stock, say, Apple, would be priced in whatever currency the owner (or broker) is located.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Funds are not automatically converted to your local currency.  It is a property of the fund or of your broker if it is offered as such.  For example, the London Stock Exchange has two Vanguard S&P 500 ETFs: VUSA priced in GBP and VUSD priced in USD.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your bank(s), but I'm pretty sure that you'd have to liquidate the holdings to move them.

Regarding the tax question, you'll be "begränsat skattskyldig" for ten years [(see Skatteverkets website, in Swedish)](https://www4.skatteverket.se/rattsligvagledning/edition/2017.6/2641.html) so it'll take a while before you can liquidate them and pay the lower tax even if you leave them in Sweden.